# Ubuntu touch os in Micromax A110 Canvas 2

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, ubuntu-for-android

I am trying to install ubuntu in my micromax mobile.

Reference [link](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

after execute below command,terminal scree stuck in "Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting"

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

is there any other way to install ubuntu in micromx mobile(V 4.4.2) or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a way to simply install Ubuntu on this device, unless you are planning to port the code yourself.

The site you linked includes a list of devices which have a working port, here:-  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices